# Launching JFrame from a button

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jframe

I've got the following button...

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Contacts contact = new Contacts();
    contact.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Contacts is just a simple JApplet...

```
 public class Contacts extends JApplet {

private JPanel jContentPane = null;

public Contacts() {
    super();
}

public void init() {
    this.setSize(500, 260);
    this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
}

private JPanel getJContentPane() {
    if (jContentPane == null) {
        jContentPane = new JPanel();
        jContentPane.setLayout(null);
        jContentPane.add(getJList(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButton1(), null);
    }
    return jContentPane;
}
  }
```

Why is what I'm doing not working? How would I launch this JFrame?

Comment: All your code is in init() that you do not call

Comment: Tried this. Calling `init()` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like `JFrame` and `JDialog`, `JApplet` is a [top-level container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). You can't put one inside the other. Instead, do something like this:

```
class Contacts extends JFrame { ... }
...
Contacts contact = new Contacts();
contact.setVisible(true);
```

If you have an existing `JApplet` that you want to display in a `JFrame`, you can create a hybrid, as shown in the examples examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513).